# C file pointer assignment to another file pointer

Tags: c, pointers, file-handling

Can I use a file pointer to open a file and then assign that pointer to another file pointer in the same program. When I have moved to original pointer to, say end of file, what is the alternate pointer pointing to, at that moment? Also, can i use "fopen" function with two different file pointers in the same program? More specifically, the following two pieces of code do compile correctly but both give segmentation fault as output. What mistake am I doing?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    FILE *file_ptr, *file_ptr_alt;
    int ch, counter=0;
    file_ptr = fopen("input.txt","r");
    file_ptr_alt = fopen("input.txt","r");
    //file_ptr_alt = file_ptr;
    while((ch=fgetc(file_ptr))!=EOF)
    {
        counter++;
    }
    printf("\nThe val of counter1 is %d\n",counter);

    while((ch=fgetc(file_ptr_alt))!=EOF)
    {
        counter++;
    }
    printf("\nThe val of counter2 is %d\n",counter);
}
```

```
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    FILE *file_ptr, *file_ptr_alt;
    int ch, counter=0;
    file_ptr = fopen("input.txt","r");
    //file_ptr_alt = fopen("input.txt","r");
    file_ptr_alt = file_ptr;
    while((ch=fgetc(file_ptr))!=EOF)
    {
        counter++;
    }
    printf("\nThe val of counter1 is %d\n",counter);

    while((ch=fgetc(file_ptr_alt))!=EOF)
    {
        counter++;
    }
    printf("\nThe val of counter2 is %d\n",counter);
}
```

Comment: "*What mistake am I doing*". One big mistake is that you are not checking the return value of all functions. Specifically, it is critical to check the return value of `fopen`. To your specific question: `file_ptr_alt = file_ptr;` does not result in a seperate file stream as you seem to think it does. After the first `while` loop `file_ptr` stream will be at the end of the file and so will `file_ptr_alt`. That means the second `while` loop condition will immediately and always be false.

Comment: The programs work if `input.txt` exists and is readable. Besides the compiler warnings you should get, there's nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In this case assigning a FILE pointer to another FILE pointer is pretty pointless. Both pointers will point to the exact same file structure.

Considering this code snippet:

```
file_ptr = fopen("input.txt","r");
file_ptr_alt = file_ptr;
```

now you can use `file_ptr_alt` or `file_ptr` for your file operations. They will do exactly the same thing.

E.g

```
a = fgetc(file_ptr_alt);
b = fgetc(file_ptr);
```

will do **exactly** the same thing as:

```
a = fgetc(file_ptr);
b = fgetc(file_ptr_alt);
```

if you've got to the end of the file with `file_ptr`, `file_ptr_alt` will also "point" to the end of the file.

---

With this code snippet it's a different story:

```
file_ptr = fopen("input.txt","r");
file_ptr_alt = fopen("input.txt","r");
```

Now `file_ptr` and `file_ptr_alt` are totally independent, if you've got to the end of the file with `file_ptr`, `file_ptr_alt` will still "point" to the beginning of the file.

---

Now for the totally unrelated question about the segmentation fault:

It's certainly because you dom't check if `fopen` fails. If `fopen` fails for example because the file you try to open does not exist (this happens very often), it returns a `NULL` FILE pointer. Now using a NULL file pointer with `fgetc` or any other related file operation, you'll get undefined behaviour, which most of the time manifests itself as segmentation fault.

You want something like this:

```
file_ptr = fopen("input.txt","r");
if (file_ptr == NULL)
{
  printf("File cannot be opned\n");
  ... take further action, but don't try to do anything
      with file_ptr

}
```